# icCube - How to do Authentication for icCube using an Apache web server

Tags: authentication, xampp, iccube, iccube-reporting

I am currently in the process of writing a WebApp to access reports from our ICCube-System. The Application page is hosted on a server different to the IcCube-server. The server is currently a local Apache server (xampp) using Basic Auth to authenticate users before they can access my htdocs. I would like my Apache to do the authentication while icCube's internal authorization manages report access, with only a single login being required.

My application is based on the [live demo for web reporting](http://demo3.iccube.com/icCube/doc/tutorial/ic3report-tutorial.html) provided by IcCube; therefore it's using explicit JavaScript authentication (it's getting the demo user data through ic3.getDemoDataSourceSettings()).

After trying to work through the [IcCube documentation](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/reporting/doc/ic3WebAppIntegration.php) on the matter, I am just as confused as before. The related page on Apache configuration lists possible configurations for Apache & icCube, but I don't understand which I should use (advantages & disadvantages) and if all of them even work with our server setup.

1. Apache Configuration Overview:
   If I set these proxy parameters in my server config, what exactly is 
   forwarded to IcCube?
2. icCube Authentication Servlet Filter:
   Does this config extract belong to IcCube or Apache? What exactly are these filters doing?

Any help with the issue or pointers to a more in-depth documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Web App (i.e. Apache) will have to forward calls related to accessing the reports in icCube. You can for example configure Apache to forward everything related to icCube as following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName your.domain.com

ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass        /icCube http://your-ip:8383/icCube
ProxyPassReverse /icCube http://your-ip:8383/icCube

</VirtualHost>
```

Then the communication between Apache and icCube is secured using Servlet Filters that are part of icCube configuration (icCube.xml):

```
IcCubeApacheAuthenticationServletFilter
IcCubeApacheGwtAuthenticationServletFilter
```

The first filter can be used for all services but GWT; for GWT you can use the second one. Here is an extract of a possible icCube.xml:

```
<xmlaComponentConfiguration>
    <!--<tcpPortNumber>8484</tcpPortNumber>-->
    <httpUrl>/icCube/xmla</httpUrl>
    <enableHttpCompression>true</enableHttpCompression>
    <filter>XMLA (Apache) Authentication</filter>
</xmlaComponentConfiguration>

<gwtServiceComponentConfiguration>
    <enableFileDownloadCompression>true</enableFileDownloadCompression>
    <filter>GWT (Apache) Authentication</filter>
</gwtServiceComponentConfiguration>

<reportingComponentConfiguration>
    <url>/icCube/doc/*</url>
    <enableCompression>true</enableCompression>
    <filter>Report Authentication</filter>
</reportingComponentConfiguration>

<gviComponentConfiguration>
    <url>/icCube/gvi</url>
    <enableCompression>true</enableCompression>
    <filter>GVI Authentication</filter>
    <filter>GVI Authentication (logout)</filter>
</gviComponentConfiguration>

<filterConfiguration>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>XMLA (Apache) Authentication</filter-name>
        <filter-class>crazydev.iccube.server.authentication.IcCubeApacheAuthenticationServletFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>GWT (Apache) Authentication</filter-name>
        <filter-class>crazydev.iccube.server.authentication.IcCubeApacheGwtAuthenticationServletFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Report Authentication</filter-name>
        <filter-class>crazydev.iccube.server.authentication.IcCubeApacheAuthenticationServletFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>GVI Authentication</filter-name>
        <filter-class>crazydev.iccube.server.authentication.IcCubeApacheAuthenticationServletFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>anonymousLogon</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>GVI Authentication (logout)</filter-name>
        <filter-class>crazydev.iccube.server.authentication.IcCubeGviLogoutAuthenticationServletFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
</filterConfiguration>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I currently pass my user data explicitly to ic3.Reporting, like this: `var dsSettings = ic3.getDemoDataSourceSettings();
    dsSettings.url =  gviUrl;
  
    var ic3reporting = new ic3.Reporting(
    {
        noticesLevel: ic3.NoticeLevel.ERROR,
        dsSettings: dsSettings}` How would I change this paragraph to work with the servlet solution? I assume I still need a similar piece of code to have getAllReportNames() get what the user is authorized to access.

Comment: Not sure to understand why you would need an explicit login. Apache Basic Auth. is performed meaning the GVI requests sent by your Javascript files will be authenticated on the server side, meaning the list of reports returned depends on the authenticated user.

Comment: Does that mean I can leave dsSettings as undefined?

Comment: Ok, I configured a local test install of IcCube and Apache similar to your example and it seems to work. I can't test it properly due to different problems, which I'm about to post in seperate questions. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Update: after testing the configurations with our live system, the icCube is no longer accessible, neither via standard online interface, nor via apache-hosted WebApp. The interface states: `HTTP ERROR: 500
Problem accessing /icCube/service.gwt. Reason:
    javax.servlet.ServletException: icCube authentication [icCube-icc-users] error : missing user credentials` I assume there's something fundamentally wrong with the configurations in our current system, any ideas? I rolled back to an earlier iccube.xml for now.

Comment: For anyone reading this: the mentioned error message is displayed due to the fact that icCube only uses the Apache-Servlet for authentication if it is specified, which means that the standard monitoring UI is only accessible via Apache redirection (it is apparently impossible for icCube to use multiple authentication servlets for the same interface, in this case the GWT interface.) Using only the Apache interface works!