# icCube - Web App unable to get resources from icCube server before external login

Tags: authentication, authorization, iccube, iccube-reporting

Follow-up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824150/iccube-how-to-do-authentication-for-iccube-using-an-apache-web-server).
I am currently trying to set up a Web Application to display reports on an intranet site, using the intranet login to authenticate users, passing the authorization process to icCube. I'm trying to get it to work with a local install of xampp apache using basic auth and a local install of icCube. My scripts are based on [icCube's live demo](http://demo3.iccube.com/icCube/doc/tutorial/ic3report-tutorial.html?ic3reportName=World%20Economy).

When I start my Web App with an empty Cache & Cookies, the App is unable to load, throwing me a lot of errors similar to these:
[WebApp errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37iwY.png)

The reason for these errors is the fact that the GET-requests for the resources are answered with code 401, which is a text/html. This means that my WebApp is not authorized to fetch the .css and similar resources from the icCube-server.

Logging into my icCube interface solves the errors, as that authorizes my browser session to get data from my icCube server.

Is there any workaround for this problem? As far as I know, the resource URIs are generated from the ic3root and ic3rootLocal passed to the ic3Start-function on the html-page, which means that I can not just pack all the .css-files into my apache folder and link them.

Is it possible to authorize my WebApp to get these resources based on the same authorization process used to get my report selection (proxy configuration)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like because Apache does not " secure " the icCube URLs with its Basic Auth. configuration and let non-authenticated requests reaching the icCube server.

Note 1: You can access " public " HTML resources (i.e., with no authentication required). For that you can use the icCube.xml  property (see doc. in the file).

Note 2: You can deploy the icCube Web Reporting application with you Web App HTML files in " Apache " and configure the Web Reporting for accessing  icCube server elsewhere (worth a different question).

Comment: With Note 1, do you mean rewriting the ic3bootstrap.js to fetch all scripts etc. from the public directory instead of the default? Also, can I find documentation on your Note 2 anywhere? Sounds like a reasonable solution, too.

Comment: Conceptually Note 1 would be very much similar to Note 2. Note 2, your Web App will contain the icCube Web Reporting application as well. On top of my head, you would need to change the location of the icCube GVI servlet to access the report definition and the OLAP engine for the MDX requests. Worth a different question.

Comment: The easy way out was placing the .js-resources in Apache (Note2); for this, I put the lib-folder in Apaches file system and changed the ic3root and ic3rootLocal to the new folder.