# icCube - WebApp always displays all reports

Tags: authorization, iccube, iccube-reporting

Follow-up question [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824150/iccube-how-to-do-authentication-for-iccube-using-an-apache-web-server). I am currently trying to set up a Web Application to display reports on an intranet site, using the intranet login to authenticate users, passing the authorization process to icCube. I'm trying to get it to work with a local install of xampp apache using basic auth and a local install of icCube. My scripts are based on [icCube's live demo](http://demo3.iccube.com/icCube/doc/tutorial/ic3report-tutorial.html?ic3reportName=World%20Economy).

When I use the WebApp, passing login information for a user, the function GetAllReportNames() fetches all available reports from our icCube server. The problem is that "available" means every report: there are also inaccessible reports displayed. There are two problems here:

1. We couldn't find an option to manage access rights for reports, only for cubes and schemas. Creating a manageable schema for every single report is not an option, though.
2. The WebApp still displays reports which can not be loaded due to schemas not being accessible, be it due to authorisation problems or the cube not being loaded currently.

Is there a ways to manage access rights for reports instead of schemas/cubes, and is there a function to get rid of unavailable reports before the list of reports is displayed by the WebApp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup access rights to the "Docs" documents from the UI. They are similar to permissions you'll find on a file system.

Comment: We finally found the option to do so; previously, we were looking for it under "Access Rights" in the Monitoring UI, while it is actually found under "Docs".